# Assign a subsequent ID to an item of List (Of) item

Tags: .net, vb.net, list

I have a List (of SomeClass) in VB.NET

I would like to assign each class a subsequent ID (1, 2, 3, etc.) whenever a new item is added to the List.

I want to know in which order the classes have been added to the list, therefore I would like to introduce these IDs.

Is that possible, and if yes, how?

Thank you.

Comment: unless you replace items (`myList(3) = myClassObj`) the index is the ID of the item.  In that case, add a Property to store the date or time added; if you cant change the class you could write a wrapper class or use the Tag property.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Add method of List class, then elements get added to the end of the list. In this case the order of elements in the list would be exactly the same as the addition order, you don't need any extra IDs

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possible approaches, depending on the level of flexibility that you have in changing your design.

The easiest approach, but one that can be fragile depending on how you call `Add`, is to `Shadow` the `List(Of T)` `Add` method (there are no useful overridable methods in `List(Of T)`:

```
Public Class MySequentialClass
    Public Property Order As Integer
End Class

Public Class MySequentialClassCollection
    Inherits System.Collections.Generic.List(Of MySequentialClass)

    Public Shadows Sub Add(oItem As MySequentialClass)
        oItem.Order = Me.Count + 1
        MyBase.Add(oItem)
    End Sub

End Class
```

The problem with this approach is that is is fragile, in that if you always call the collection's Add method directly, you are ok, but if you (or other code, such as a grid) uses the ICollection interface, your shadow method may not be called.

Because of this fragility, I prefer to inherit from `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of T)` in cases like this. When you do, you can override both the `InsertItem` method since it will always be called. In addition, if you need to renumber when an item is removed, you can also override the `RemoveItem` method.

```
Public Class MySequentialClassCollection
    Inherits System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of MySequentialClass)

    Protected Overrides Sub InsertItem(index As Integer, item As MySequentialClass)
        item.Order = Me.Count + 1
        MyBase.InsertItem(index, item)
    End Sub

End Class
```